# The Clean Architecture and the dependency rule for the 3rd and 4th layer

Tags: architecture

In his [blog post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), Uncle bob defines the layers of the clean architecture and states the dependency rule:

> This rule says that source code dependencies can only point inwards. Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle

I have troubles reconciling this rule with reality when it comes to the green and blue layers (on his diagram). These are the 2 outer layers, respectively the 3rd and 4th layers from the center.

I understand what it means for the inner layers, for example a controller can pass entities to a use case and let it do its things. The Use case then never needs to know about the controller, and the entities never know about the use case.

But when it comes to the controllers (3rd layer) and an element from the 4th layer - for example a database - I don't understand how this is possible. Uncle bob says that all the SQL (if there is any) should be restricted to this layer. But that means that the 3rd layer *knows* about the 4th one, since it's *asking something* from it.

Would you be able to shed a light here please?

Answer (score 0):

> But that means that the 3rd layer knows about the 4th one, since it's asking something from it.

No. 3rd layer does not need to directly depend on and/or know about 4th layer. 3rd layer uses gateways to interact with database, i.e. it declares contracts which are implemented in 4th layer. So for example you can have a repository interface declared on this level, but actual implementation is done on the 4th, so 3rd layer actually does not know anything about SQL, or even outbound HTTP/GRPC/GraphQL requests (which can also be used to query for data in some cases).

P.S.

If you are looking into different architecture approaches I would also recommend to look into [Vertical Slice Architecture](https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/) ([video presentation](https://youtu.be/SUiWfhAhgQw)) which as far as I understand is quite similar to Feature Folders approach which personally I've grown fond over the last years (see [this](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/asp-net-core-feature-slices-for-asp-net-core-mvc) and [this](https://ardalis.com/api-feature-folders/))

Comment: AFAIU, what you're saying is that the 3rd layer interacts with the 4th through interfaces. But let's say we're implementing the repository you mentioned with OOP. The repository exposes an interface to query data, and implements the SQL privately. 3rd layers uses the interface of the object to query data. But it still references the name of the object. Does it violate the dependency rule " the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle"? Is the repository in the 3rd or 4th layer? Uncle Bod doesn't mention gateways.

Comment: Thanks for the links by the way, I'm very interested

Comment: @JPFrancoia _"But it still references the name of the object."_ - no, it does not, it uses abstractions of it's own layer (DTOs), like any other layer (or even entities in case of anemic domain model though Uncle Bob does not approve it :-). _"Uncle Bod doesn't mention gateways."_  - look at the discussed picture closely.